# How can I embed a WordPress blog into another site?

Tags: wordpress, iweb

I currently make my website using iWeb. Is there a way that I can embed a WordPress blog into the site? Either through an easy option or through coding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done, but not through iWeb. You will need to do it through code (in Wordpress' case, PHP).

Here's a guide for integrating Wordpress with your site, I'm afraid laying out the steps would be far too long an answer for SO.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_Wordpress_with_Your_Website

Comment: Can I add PHP directly through iWeb?

Answer (score 2):

I would agree that an iFrame is the easiest way...

However there are some real problems with this method.  Wordpress has it's own automatic navigation which visitors will use, taking them to places that may be different than your normal navigation would. Categories and other that cannot be switched off.  You can remove these through some tweeking of the css but then you might as well do the php thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a PC and using NetObjects instead of iWeb, but I used iframes to do mine and think the technique could work for iWeb. Basically it involved adding the iframe HTML, some javascript to adjust the iframe hieght, and some tweaks to the WordPress theme to get rid of the header.

I put together a tutorial video on how I did it here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GuocgQlCmw The description on youtube includes links to where I got the information on how to do it and my blog entry describing the process.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make an iframe in iweb and insert your wordpress blog in the iframe. Many people do it this way.